# What does MyPictureBox.Location represents in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

Let MyPictureBox be a control of type PictureBox.
What does 
     MyPictureBox.Location         and
     MyPictureBox.Location.X
ACTUALLY returns ??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MyPictureBox.Location;
```

returns a `Point` datatype data that contains the location of the `picturebox`, `X` and `Y`.

`X` is the space from the left of the form to the `picturebox`. `Y` is the space from the top of the form to the `picturebox`.

```
    MyPictureBox.Location.X
```

Just returns `X` which is of `int` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says:

> Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container.

Did you do any searching?

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx

Comment: Yes. i did. But whats unsettling about X and Y being int is that its distances from Left and Top (relative to its) are in pixels or what ??

Comment: Yes, they are in pixels